# Show div when hover another div using only css

Tags: html, css

I have searched the web for this one but didn't find anything similar.

Say we have div A and div B. When hover on div A, div b should be visible ON (should look like overwriting) div A and not placed under.

It should appear like only the content of div A has changed to content of div B.

How can this be done in pure CSS and HTML?

```
#container > div {
    display: none
}
#container > div:first-child {
    display: block
}
#container > div:hover + div {
    display: block

<div id="container">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code or html you can include in the question?  That is always helpful.

Comment: in pure CSS it is only possible when div B is a child of div A.

Comment: @Sven Bieder This statement is wrong, it may also be a sibling.

Comment: @feeela Yes you are right I haven't thought about that possibility. But that only works when you don't need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will work, but *only* if the two divs are adjacent and b follows a.

```
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #f00
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

If you have divs in between use ~

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    background: #f00
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="c">Div C</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

To go the other way around, unfortunately you will need Javascript

```
// Pure Javascript
document.getElementById('b').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
}
document.getElementById('b').onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundColor = '';
}

// jQuery
$('#b').hover(
  function(){$('#a').css('background', '#F00')}, 
  function(){$('#a').css('background', '')}
);
```

Full fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p7hLL/5/

Comment: This is changing the background-color of the Div B when Div A is hover. How do Div B show over Div A when Div A is hover?

Comment: @M.El-Set That way round is not possible using CSS alone.

Comment: I've added how to do the reverse, but unfortunately it is only possible with Javascript.

Comment: @M.El-Set - If the answer solved your problem, please make sure to mark it as such using the checkmark next to the answer. That way the person answering gets credit, other people can easily tell that it solved your problem, and people will be more inclined to answer your future questions.

Comment: PassKit gave the best answer, i think. He said that it is not possible in pure css. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use the selector `+` or `~` which aren't compatible with some browsers, it is just possible if the `<div />` to show (e.g. `div#b`) is a child of the `<div />` to hover (e.g. `div#a`).

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>

<style>
    div#b {
        display: none;
    }

    div#a:hover div#b {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: "It is just possible if the DIV is a child" This is wrong. There are other working solutions as well, e.g. the one from @PassKit.

Comment: @feeela go on reading my sentence, I made an update few minutes ago

Comment: "not browser-compatible at all" is still wrong. It is indeed not supported by IE6. In fact the general sibling selector is widely supported and has no known flaws. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: Ok, I changed it. But there are some more IE's which cannot act with this line of CSS. More compatible is it to make this with Javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Its works, but your css should be like this

```
<style>
#b{display:none;}
div#a:hover div#b{display:inline}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

It works; you can try nested css like:

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a:hover{
  .b{
     /* properties of hover */
   }
}
```