# Show DIV on hover of other DIV that is not parent with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now I can do that with CSS, but it works only when the hidden div is a child of a parent. You hover on parent div and set CSS on hover to display the child from `none` to `block`, something like that.

But how do you do that if the hidden block is outside the div that you hover and the hidden one appears?

Example:

```
<div class="field-1"></div>
<div class="field-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt consequat tristique. Curabitur vestibulum semper nulla id ornare.</div>
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/23u3rmx5/ when you hover over red block the .field-2 must appear below it. You cannot move the div structure, e.g. move .field-2 inside .field-1, I can do that, but that's not the solution.

Thanks for helping and cheers! Have a good weekend!

Comment: there is no jquery / javascript code inside fiddle..what you have tried so far..???

Comment: I accept any solutions with jQuery too if needed. Thanks.

Comment: okk that is fine but first you have to show what you have tried so far and we will correct your code...we will not write code for you..

Comment: That's the problem, I only am experienced with CSS solutions. Not much of JS skills.

Comment: okk that is good i thought you are expecting some js code...+1 good question..

Comment: @TJ I just found [couple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/show-div-on-hover-with-only-css) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766141/css-show-div-when-another-div-is-hover) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382149/show-div-when-hover-another-div-using-only-css) out there. Not sure if I should close them all. What do you think?

Comment: @HashemQolami close them all, i marked it with the one which was easiest for me to find..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular instance you can use [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to target the element having `.field-2` class as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/23u3rmx5/2/)**

```css
.field-1:hover + .field-2 { display: block; }
```

Also if the `.field-2` don't immediately follow the `.field-1`, you could try using [general sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/general_sibling_selectors) instead:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/23u3rmx5/3/)**

```css
.field-1:hover ~ .field-2 { display: block; }
```

Comment: Hey that's awesome. But that plus sign, how many browsers supports it? Is this major feature in all browsers or something fancy? Thanks again.

Comment: @OptimusPrime It's supported even in Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: It's worth noting that adjacent sibling combinator is a part of [CSS selectors level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) while general sibling combinator belongs to [CSS selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). But both are supported in very wide range of web browsers including IE7.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/23u3rmx5/1/

```
$(".field-1").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".field-2").show();
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".field-2").hide();
});
```

Though use Hashem's solution if your sure you wont be changing the DOM structure in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
.field-1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
.field-1:hover + .field-2{
   display: block;  
}
.field-2 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
<script>
$('.field-1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.field-2').show();
  });
$('.field-1').mouseleave(function(){
$('.field-2').hide();
  });
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/23u3rmx5/5/)