# hover div to show another div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Any idea how to get this to work?

CSS:

```
.otherDiv {
  opacity: 0;
}

.innerDiv:hover + .otherDiv {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
      <h4>Show content</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="otherDiv">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Basically I want otherDiv to show only if you hover over innerDiv.

Here is a fiddle with my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/4ghws6wz/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ghws6wz/2/ Here you can see more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382149/show-div-when-hover-another-div-using-only-css

Comment: Use jQuery to manage these types of actions.  CSS can do the job only if your have carefully designed mark-up, which may limit your page layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot do that with CSS but

You can try using jQuery, see the fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/4ghws6wz/3/

```
$(".innerDiv").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().css('opacity', 1);
});
$(".innerDiv").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).parent().siblings().css('opacity', 0);
});
```

Or

```
$(".innerDiv").mouseover(function(){
    $(".otherDiv").css('opacity', 1);
});
$(".innerDiv").mouseout(function(){
    $(".otherDiv").css('opacity', 0);
});
```

> CSS Selector Documentation :
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: this worked perfectly and doesn't require a ton of code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the outer div instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ghws6wz/1/

```
.otherDiv {
  opacity: 0;
}

.outerDiv:hover + .otherDiv {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: is there no way to make it work using the inner div? Because I want to have multiple inner divs that will change the background of otherDiv, depending on which innerDiv you hover.

Comment: Did not find a way yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".innerDiv").hover(function(){
        $(".otherDiv").css("opacity", 1);
    })

    $(".innerDiv").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".otherDiv").css("opacity", 0);
    })
})
```

on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ghws6wz/4/